# Loading searches (impressions) from google search console and google api

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, google-search-console

I'm trying to make an analytics page and that also contains having the impressions of the past 30 days. I tried making one using google's api but the result didn't work.

My code:

```
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
        onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
        onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
    <script>
        function handleClientLoad() {
            gapi.load('client', initClient);
        }

        function initClient() {
            gapi.client.init({
                apiKey: 'nuh-uh das my api key',
                discoveryDocs: ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/webmasters/v3/rest'],
            }).then(function () {
                // API is ready
                // You can make requests to the Search Console API here
                fetchData(); // Call the function to fetch and display data
            });
        }

        function fetchData() {
            gapi.client.webmasters.searchanalytics.query({
                siteUrl: 'https://masterrealm.net',
                startDate: '2023-01-01',
                endDate: '2023-01-31',
                dimensions: ['query'],
            }).then(function (response) {
                // Process the response and display search data on your webpage
                const searchesElement = document.getElementById('searches');
                if (searchesElement) {
                    searchesElement.textContent = response.result.rows[0].keys[0];
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

any help incase I have done something wrong?

Comment: incase someone is wondering i have a <h3> with id #searches so it should gets displayed there